# css - my boxes are misaligned

Tags: html, css

I just started learning the basics of CSS and HTML and I'm struggling to understand why my boxes are misaligned.

To give you a brief background, everytime I enter a new "vendor" in the wordpress CMS, it will show up on the overall vendor page as seen in the image attached. However, there is always some kind of misalignment happening. Can anyone help me out with this?

`

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php
        $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'order' => 'desc',
        'taxonomy' => 'vender',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        );

    ?>

    <?php 
        $vendors = get_categories( $args );
        foreach ( $vendors as $vendor ):   
        //print_r($vendor); 
        $image = get_field('image', 'vender_'.$vendor->term_id);
        $location = get_field('location', 'vender_'.$vendor->term_id);
        $cuisines = get_field('cuisines', 'vender_'.$vendor->term_id);
    ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="partner">
                <div class="image-partner">
                    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/access/viewmenu?vendor=<?php echo $vendor->slug;?>" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" /></a>
                </div>
                <h3 class="name-partner"><?php echo $vendor->name;?></h3>
                <div class="desc-partner"><?php echo $vendor->description;?></div>
                <div class="loc-partner">Locations: <?php if (sizeof($location) >1) echo implode(",", $location); else echo $location[0];?></div>

             </div>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>


    </div>

    <!-------------- Class Studio ------------------->
    <div class="row">
    <?php
        $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'order' => 'desc',
        'taxonomy' => 'studios',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        );

    ?>

    <?php 
        $vendors = get_categories( $args );
        foreach ( $vendors as $vendor ):   
        //print_r($vendor); 
        $image = get_field('image', 'studios_'.$vendor->term_id);

    ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="partner">
                <div class="image-partner">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <h3 class="name-partner"><?php echo $vendor->name;?></h3>
                <div class="desc-partner"><?php echo $vendor->description;?></div> 

             </div>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>


    </div>

</div>`
```

[misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnCyW.jpg)

[misalignment 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL382.jpg)

Comment: Give them all a standard height

Comment: if the requirement is dynamic  height  you should take a look on masonry if not yet just define a fix height and go for ellipsis for the content

Comment: they are not misaligned, they are following their default behavior. Go for masonry layout. There are multiple 3rd party plugins for that

Answer (score 0):

try to use nth-child may it helps you

```
.row .partner:nth-child(3n+1)
{
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the container a max height unless the inside content is variable?

`.selector{
  max-height: 300px;
}`